# Is higher inductance always better in voltage regulator? and 2 other questions

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, boost

I am specifically looking at a boost converters. But I guess the same answers apply for buck converters etc(?):

**questions 1:**
Is it allways better to have a bigger inductor in a switched power supply? for example is it always better to have 100uH than 10uH?

**questions 2:**
and when it comes to EMC/EMI: is it better to have a regulator with slower Switching Frequency than a higher Switching Frequency? is this a important aspect to look at when chosing an regulator? (for not sending out magnetic or electric fields?)

**questions 3:**
if you have an application that needs 50mAmp current for example: do you just need the Saturation current-rating and the Current Rating (Amps) to be higher than 50mAmp and it will work? or any other value to look at? are there any rule for how much "headroom" one needs?

Comment: please don't ask 6 questions in one question post. I'm removing all but your first question – please don't hesitate to ask *separate* questions for these (you can still find them in the edit history).

Comment: *is it always better to have 100 µH than 10 µH?* No, if the 100 uH inductor is more expensive, gives more losses, takes more space, isn't recommended for the switching IC I'm using. And even if 100 uH is "always better", what about 1 mH (=1000 uH)? Or 10 mH or 100 mH? See where that is going? More isn't "always better".

Comment: I've rolled this back and voted to close as needs more focus since there is already an answer that addresses the multiple questions.

Answer (score 1):

> questions 1: Is it allways better to have a bigger inductor in a
> switched power supply? for example is it always better to have 100uH
> than 10uH?

A higher inductance is better. But, a higher inductance means more turns, thus higher resistance. You have to calculate the losses in order to determine the real benefit to have a higher inductance, in practice they tend to use small inductance.

> questions 2: and when it comes to EMC/EMI: is it better to have a
> regulator with slower Switching Frequency than a higher Switching
> Frequency? is this a important aspect to look at when chosing an
> regulator? (for not sending out magnetic or electric fields?)

It's more a challenge for the PCB manufacturing, regardless of the used frequency - many layers would shield electric fields. There is a possibility to use shielded inductors.

> questions 3: if you have an application that needs 50mAmp current for
> example: do you just need the Saturation current-rating and the
> Current Rating (Amps) to be higher than 50mAmp and it will work? or
> any other value to look at? are there any rule for how much "headroom"
> one needs?

Yes of course. The inductor shall be choosen according to the peak current value. 50mA doesn't mean anything, it's just a mean value. The peak value is a function of voltage, duty time, inductance. You will find the formulas in many application notes from many buck/boost IC manufacturers like TI, AD, ST, Maxim,...

Comment: One thing I would like to add, the step response becomes worse with a too large inductor for a given output capacitor.

Comment: Thank you for the answers!! A follow up question: "The inductor shall be choosen according to the peak current value"   so if the peak current is 2 amp for example. Should both Saturation current-rating and the Current Rating (Amps) to be higher than 2 amp then?   or is it 2 amp for saturation but 50 mAmp for current rating?

Comment: The peak current has to be < than saturation current, meanwhile the RMS current through the inductor shall be <= rated current. The current through an inductor is a triangle shape. What you say 50mA is ambiguous since it could be a mean output or input value. I suggest you to visit TI web page, and try their online tool Webench, choose the type buck/boost,.. then input/output parameters. The tool will offer you different results: lowest BOM price, lowest PCB size, best performance. You will get the entire list of inductor PN.TI has also very good datasheets with lots of theory and formulas.

Comment: 50 mAmps is Iout.  Actually it is partically because of webench I am confused. I asked another questions about webench here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594218/idc-irms-isat-and-current-rating-inductor