# IDC, Irms, Isat and Current Rating (inductor). Webench

Tags: voltage-regulator, inductor, boost

See image.

When choosing alternative inductor with webench it has the value "**IDC**" in the top in "recommended limits" and "**current rating (Irms/Isat**)" below.

Even thou "IDC" and "Irms/Isat" are not called the same I assume these are the same (?) since they seem to have simular numerical value limits in Webench.

**Irms** and **Isat** I understand is two independent values in reality and should be treated as sutch. But Irms and Isat have (for some reason) been reprecented in webench as one parameter(!).
So I understand I need to have both the **Irms** (Irms is same as **Current Rating (Amps)** at Digikey?) and **Isat** bigger than the minimum numerical value displayed in Webench (1.39 amps).

So,**IDC** and **Irms** and **Isat** are two (not three) parameters but should have same value according to webench.

And **IDC** and **Irms** and **Current Rating** are all the same thing?

correct?...

And sorry for maybe a stupid question. But I get confused when everythings is called diffrent at diffrent places...
I just wanted to double check this.

[image: webench picture]

Comment: They probably have a mix of values specified as saturation and RMS current by the manufacturers.

Comment: The RMS value of the pure DC value is the same. They don't specify the current rating as 1.39A sine wave rms, rather 1.39A I_DC. The current waveform of the inductor can be sine, triangle,... it depends on the application. In a switching PSU you could have DC+triangle if operated in CCM mode, or you have tips of triangles if in DCM mode.